# Xcode 6.0.1 Instruments iOS8 - App not behaving normally when profiling on device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, instruments

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated on why this might be happening. I'm trying to profile my app using the Allocations trace template (the same happens when using any other template). My app is comprised of some cocoapod libraries and another imported project which gets built as a library, if that might be of any relevance.

When i run the app on my ipad Air the app runs fine. A drawer controller and a collectionview gets pushed as it should, the app runs normally. However, as soon as I try to profile the very same app on the device, it does not behave as expected. (I have also tried this on the simulator & it does the same thing)

The app will hang when doing certain operations, like when pressing a button in the app that should normally push a new view controller, it will just hang. I've looked everywhere for an answer, with no luck. I've played around with the various settings in Instruments, I've tried changing the code-signing settings as suggested elsewhere. Tried both Debug & Release. To no avail.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Am I the only one experiencing this strangeness with Xcode 6 Instruments on iOS8?

Comment: Same here, my app starts but hangs half way through the display of the main view and is totally unresponsive after that (CPU usage is null, it's not doing anything). Any hint greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with instruments. I fixed it by removing the NSLog from my app. I am not sure why this might be happening.

Comment: It also works for me. The app hangs after its first NSLog. After I remove it everything's fine. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm I have also been experiencing strange behaviour with Xcode Instruments 6.0.1 / iOS8. I first noticed the issues with version 6.0. When running from device (iPad air) and selecting installed apps from Instruments and starting the app from Instruments, some of the app functionality fails. However, when selecting an the same already running app and then starting profiling while the app is running this functionality works. I have also not been able to get the Leaks tool to generate any activity on Instruments 6.0+ whereas it had no issues in Instruments/Xcode 5.

So basically try profiling the already running app to see if it fixes any of the odd behaviour. Also try profiling while in simulator might also provide different results.